# Animate roundedrect with CoreAnimation

Tags: swift, swift3, core-animation, uibezierpath

Guys I have the following code to produce a bezierpath

```
firstLine.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: frameSize.width / 2.2, y: frameSize.height / 2.6, width: 4, height: 4), cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
```

I try to animate the firstLine by moving it to the right of the screen by x value and back to the original position. But I don't know what to use for the keyPath in the animation.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "??")
animation.toValue = // this should be the position to move?
animation.duration = 0.5 // duration of the animation
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut) // animation curve is Ease Out
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth // keep to value after finishing
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false // don't remove after finishing
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = HUGE
```

Can someone help me out on this :)

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cabasicanimation

> You create an instance of CABasicAnimation using the inherited init(keyPath:) method, specifying the key path of the property to be animated in the render tree.

Example of what you want:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.fromValue = [startX, startY]
animation.toValue = [destinationX, destinationY]
```

Comment: The position keypath is somehow not working for bezierpath.

Comment: @Reshad Can you add the code you're using to move the bezier path?